# What is the correct MIME type for tgz file? and how to send a tgz file to an android app using adp

Tags: android

What is the correct MIME type for .tgz file? and how to send a tgz file to an android app using adb

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -n com.example.destination/com.example.destination.MainActivity --es command \"reboot\" -t text/plain
```

the above mentioned is the adb command to send the plain text to an android app. cam someone help me knowing the mime type for .tgz files and command to send the tgz file to an android app.

Comment: This is a question that belongs on https://android.stackexchange.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: What parameters you have to set is often specific to the app you want to open the `tgz` file with. Some expect just a certain file extension, other a mime-type and some may be both. Check the AndroidManifest.xml file of the target app for `<intent-filter>` elements as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097734/150978